# INSERT INTO different fields in different database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm quite confused with sql INSERT INTO. Do I need to put **JOIN**? or **INNER JOIN** when I'm going to put into different table?

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO forum_topic (topic_title, topic_message, thread_id) 
VALUES 
('$topic','$message','$thread_id')";
```

I know this code is works for only one table but not for two. However, what I want is `$message` into **post_message** in other table.

In **forum_topic** table, there is **post_id**, **post_message**, **date**, and **topic_id**.

But there is **forum_post** table where I want to put `$message` into **post_message** in **forum_post**.

So, in **forum_post** table, there is **post_id**, **post_message**, **date**, and **topic_id**.

So do I need to JOIN or INNER JOIN? I don't know which one I should code them.

PS : I know the question is quite hard for you to understand. How I wish i can put image but I don't have 10 reputations, so i decided to do like this.

Comment: i have seen dozens of questions this week on inserting data into two tables at once with one insert statement which is impossible. why don't you read the mysql properly first and ask question

Comment: I tried to comment there unfortunately, i don't have any reputation to comment there. It's different to mine anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot insert into multiple tables with one query, but you can use transactions to make sure that the operation is atomic.

```
BEGIN;
Your queries here
COMMIT;
```

When you need to execute several interdepending queries, some of them might result in error. So to keep the database consistent you would like to execute them as all-or-none (You can read about [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)).
MySQL also supports transactions but only with some of its storage engines (e.g. InnoDB, but not MyISAM).

The pseudo-code of usage looks like this.

```
start transaction
try {
  execute query 1
  execute query 2
  ...
  commit transaction
catch {
  rollback transaction
}
```

If you are using PDO, look at these [functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). 
In case of mysql_query, you can use
`mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");`
`mysql_query("COMMIT");`
`mysql_query("ROLLBACK");`

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? I'm quite confused what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use joins.  You use separate queries for each table.

```
insert into table1
(field1, field2, etc)
values
(value1, value2, etc);

insert into table2
(field1, field2, etc)
values
(value1, value2, etc);
```

Comment: `$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO forum_topic (topic_title, thread_id)
        VALUES ('$topic', '$thread_id')
 INSERT INTO forum_post (post_message)
 VALUES ('$message')";`    I did that and it doesn't work well too. For important note, this **forum_topic** has a connection to **forum_post** such as **topic_id**. What should I do with that?

Comment: You have to get the topic_id that was generated from your first insert and use it in your second.

Answer (score 0):

To insert into multiple tables you must use multiple queries.

Example:

```
$sqlinsert1 = "INSERT INTO forum_topic1 (topic_title1, topic_message1, thread_id1) 
VALUES 
('$topic1','$message1','$thread_id1')";

$sqlinsert2 = "INSERT INTO forum_topic2 (topic_title2, topic_message2, thread_id2) 
VALUES 
('$topic2','$message2','$thread_id2')";
```

Join are used for Selecting queries.

Example for a Join:

```
$sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM forum_topic 
Join table2 on thread_id = table2id
WHERE topic_title = $topic";
```